# jQuery Validator plugin isn't doing anything

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am trying to use the jQuery Validator plugin. I have never used a jQuery plug in before so I expect that I am missing something simple. I want to use this plugIn to validate a simple form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Programming Cards</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#myForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    name: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: true
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="myForm">
            <label for="name">Name: </label>
            <input id="name" name="name"/> <br />
            <label for="password">Password: </label>
            <input id="password" name="password" /> <br />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this code no validation takes place at all. The form can be submitted regardless of what the input is.

The goal is to make it so that the user can only submit the form if both the name and password text inputs have been filled out.

I downloaded the jQuery Validator plug in, I cut the file called jquery.validate.js and pasted that file into the same folder that index.php is in (index.php is the file shown below).

I know that the type of validation I am doing is very simple. I know that it could be done without this plugIn. However, I want to solve this problem using this plugIn because I intent to use this plugIn to do more complex validation in the future.

**Summary of Goal**

I want to use the jQuery Validator plug in to ensure that both text boxes have values in them BEFORE the form can be submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code with document ready:

```
<script> 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
```

this is because jquery can't find that field before DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: great that worked thanks sorry for the simple question. I am very new to jQuery

Comment: @user3108671 - Welcome to SO, please don`t forget to accept this as answer, if that solve your issue.

Comment: Hardy, providing a link to jQuery documentation about 'how to use' / tutorial will help even more the OP.